# Clothing Not deforming in engine, using mesh deformer

Tags: mesh

[image]

As you can see in Blender the clothes animates fine-ish, but in UE4 some parts don't seem to want to animate, i believe this is happening to more then just the shirt.

Answer (score 1):

The mesh deform modifier is a custom piece of blender functionality and is not supported outside blender.

Only shape keys and the armature modifier are reasonable reliably supported in cross application use as methods of mesh deformation. These are the only ones supported in the fbx file format that I am aware of.

Comment: Yes your are correct, that was my mistake.